# Does a video file which is a still image have a smaller file size than one with moving image?

Tags: video, compression

Purely out of interest and bare in mind I have no real understanding of compression.

Does a compressed video file with the same image for multiple frames have a smaller size than one where every frame is different?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think this question is a little OT, surely are better places where to ask, but

yes, a compressed video file with same image is (much) smaller than one with a different picture in every frame:

technically a video with same image is a little big bigger than the single image, since all frame after first do not have differences, while a video with all complete different picture (theorically) can be up to a little more of the sum of the size of each picture.